# How to overcome Python's two complement notation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary

How to overcome Python's two complement's notation and get `0b011111111111111` in the last result? Can it be done mathematically? Just can't figure out for hours already...

```
output = 0xFFFF
for i in (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15):
    a = 1 << i
    print(bin(output^a))
```

Result:

```
0b1111111111111110 ✅
0b1111111111111101 ✅
0b1111111111111011 ✅
0b1111111111110111 ✅
0b1111111111101111 ✅
0b1111111111011111 ✅
0b1111111110111111 ✅
0b1111111101111111 ✅
0b1111111011111111 ✅
0b1111110111111111 ✅
0b1111101111111111 ✅
0b1111011111111111 ✅
0b1110111111111111 ✅
0b1101111111111111 ✅
0b1011111111111111 ✅
0b111111111111111  ❌  <<<< how to make this equal to 0b011111111111111 ?
```

Comment: What makes you think that's anything to do with two's complement? The issue is that you want your number to have a leading zero, isn't it?

Comment: for exemple, if I do ~0b111 I get 0b1000, but I want 0b000.

Comment: @Rodrigo but that's something different than the example code and issue you've provided...

Comment: @JonClements Yes, maybe I didn't go direcly to the point in my question..

Answer (score 3):

You can also do it using the [`rjust`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_rjust.htm) method:

```
output = 0xFFFF
for i in (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15):
    a = 1 << i
    print('0b' + bin(output^a)[2:].rjust(16,'0'))
```

As @wim pointed out, you could use [`zfill`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_zfill.htm) to fill with zeroes:

```
print('0b' + bin(output^a)[2:].zfill(16))
```

Comment: To just zero-pad with a string method, `str.zfill` would be more canonical choice than `str.rjust`.

Comment: @wim thank you for pointing that out. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**To print binary digits with leading zeros**, use string formatting. For example to request 16 bits with leading zero padding:

```
print("0b" + format(output^a, "016b"))
```

If you have f-strings available (Python 3.6+):

```
>>> f"0b{output^a:016b}"
'0b0111111111111111'
```

**To [invert a number without changing the bit length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53471470/how-to-print-a-numbers-binary-representation-with-leading-zeros/53471536?noredirect=1#comment93813765_53471470)**, here is the mathematical trick:

```
>>> n = 7
>>> f"0b{n:b}"
'0b111'
>>> L = n.bit_length()
>>> f"0b{2**L-1-n:0{L}b}"
'0b000'
```

Comment: First example could be written as: `'0b{:016b}'.format(output ^ a)`

Comment: Yeah, that's the great thing about Python, there's always more ways to do the same thing..

Comment: Really great answer... Happens that  I need the output to be in binary, any easy way to achieve that?

Comment: No, that's Perl. *There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.*

Comment: Wow... that maths trick just looks horrible as an f-string :)

Comment: I think I will need to make another question (string -> binary)

Comment: Yeah, it's gross.  I've tried to make it look better by factoring out the bit length.